# Runtime Java Module Generation for Game Plugins

Tags: java, modding, plugin

Edit:
Clarification:

I want to create a named module during runtime and put dynamically loaded classes into the created module.

I am attempting to build a framework that allows for code generation that is compatible with Java 9's module system. I require the ability to load some generated byte code into a "virtual" module.

From what I can tell after looking though the Java code there are no exported and public methods that allow me to do anything like this, but I am sure I am missing something.

For an example, let's say this class is generated for the module "handler".

```
package handler;

public class ModHandler{
    public static String fireEvent(){
        return "This is a string from the generated module!";
    }
}
```

How do I make the "handler" module and load the bytecode into it?
How would you add exports and requires into the module?
I do not want to write anything to the disk to implement this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946338/how-do-i-programmatically-compile-and-instantiate-a-java-class

Comment: That is not the problem here, I understand code generation/modification and class loading before Java 9. I need to know how to load them into a programicly defined module.

Comment: is this question still active? or is it already answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46112809/is-it-possible-to-load-and-unload-jdk-and-custom-modules-dynamically-in-java-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a `ModuleLayer` from a `Configuration`. This requires a `Set` of `Path`s to pass to a `ModuleFinder` instance that can be created with `ModuleFinder.of`.

This example lists the jars in `plugins` and loads the modules.

```
// List all jar files in ./plugins
File[] pluginFiles = new File("plugins").listFiles((f,n)->n.endsWith(".jar"));
// Convert to Paths
Arrays.stream(pluginFiles).map(File::toPath).collect(Collectors.toSet());
// Create a module finder from those jars
ModuleFinder finder = ModuleFinder.of(Set.of(pluginFiles));
// Get the boot config
Configuration parentConfig = ModuleLayer.boot().configuration();
// Create a new configuration
Configuration configuration = parentConfig.resolve(
    finder,
    ModuleFinder.of(),
    // This gets the names of all the modules and tells the Config to load them
    finder.findAll().stream().map(mr->mr.descriptor().name()).collect(Collectors.toList())
);
// Create the ModuleLayer, you can now interact with the modules
ModuleLayer layer = ModuleLayer.boot().defineModulesWithOneLoader(configuration, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
```

This was so much harder to find than one might think, with this you can create a custom `ModuleFinder` and do weird and wonderful things.

Comment: Glad to hear that you found a solution! Don't forget to [mark it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/228147) - it helps others who may run into the same or similar problems.

Comment: I did not even try to because I am used to a 24 hour delay before I can do that. :-P